# Running Services.msc as a different User C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, runas

I have a requirement to create a simple windows forms application that allows an admin user to manage the Services on remote servers. We don't want to give the admins the usernames and passwords to the servers so these will be encrypted and stored in a database.

My question is whether or not it is possible to spawn a `Services.msc` window when impersonating one of the users stored within the database?

I have looked at the `ProcessStartInfo` class but because `Services.msc` is not an executable it does not seem to like executing this. Any ideas on a simple way of doing the actual impersonation and loading of `Services.msc` - say off a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File extension **msc** is associated with mmc.exe. You'll want to start the following:

```
mmc.exe services.msc
```

Answer (score 1):

Spender was faster, so he gets the credits. Here is what I did, just in case it is useful to someone.

```
SecureString ss = new SecureString();
ss.AppendChar('X');
// other calls to AppendChar
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    UserName = "XXX", Password = ss, Domain = "XXX",
      UseShellExecute = false,
      FileName = "mmc", Arguments = "services.msc"
  };
Process.Start(psi);
```